# Max flow and Matching problem

Tags: reductions, np-hard, approximation

Where can i find a list of problems reducible to max flow and matching problems. I need such examples to learn and practice .

Comment: There are some monographs on these topics. On network flow, there is Network Flows: Theory, Algorithms, and Applications. On matching, there's the classic Matching Theory by Lovász and Plummer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the book "*Algorithm Design*" by Kleinberg and Tardos, Kevin Wayne has [a set of slides](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~wayne/kleinberg-tardos/pdf/07NetworkFlowII.pdf) (second part [here](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~wayne/kleinberg-tardos/pdf/07NetworkFlowIII.pdf)) where the following applications of max flow and matching are presented in some detail:

- survey design
- airline scheduling
- image segmentation
- project selection
- baseball elimination
- assignment problem
- input-queued switching

For even more examples, have a look into the exercises of Chapter 7 of Kleinberg and Tardos' book, or into the exercises of the book "*Network Flows: Theory, Algorithms, and Applications*" by Ahuja, Magnanti and Orlin.

Comment: thanks , exactly what i needed to see .